# 3d to 2d transformation with projectPoints in opencv

Tags: opencv, 3d, transformation, camera-calibration

I have calculated translation (`rvecs`) and (`tvecs`) using opencv calibrateCamera. In calibrateCamera(), I have given set object and image points from 4 different depth (z).

```
calibrateCamera(objectPts, imagePts, imSize, cameraMatrix, distortionCoef, rvecs, tvecs);
```

Hence rvecs and tvecs vectors having size 4 (I am getting 4 different rotation and translation vecs).

Now for a new 3d point I can use one of the rotation and translation vector returned by above vectors.

But how I will select which rotation translation vector I need to use with `projectPoints()` to get the correct 3d to 2d transformation?

I have static camera, I have set of points from one plane (all the points in that plane is having same `z` value).  Likewise I have set of points from different planes. Now for for each plane I have different rotation and translation vectors (calculated using calibrate camera). Now for a new 3d point in different plane, I need to calculate the 2d image point, using above rotation and translation vectors that I obtained.

Comment: you must choose the one of your current camera position. If that differs from the ones that you used on calibration (which is very likely for a non-static camera) you have to find out r and t for your current camera position. So easiest is to fix your camera position ;)

Comment: @Micka I have updated my question

Comment: ah ok. the camera position is the same for all samples, but represented in different coordinate systems! so you can choose any ONE of these to fix the coordinate system, or transform the coordinate system further (maybe you want to have the coordinate origin at some fixed point in the real world?

Comment: @Micka   all object points are in same coordinate system but points are from different z plane,

Comment: with same origin position (except z plane)? then r should be the same for each dataset if I don't miss sth.?

Comment: I have same origin position, then I tooke set of point in real world coordinate varying x and y and making z values constant. and found rotation and translation matrix.   Then I have taken another z plane took points from that and using image and object points in this plane I have calculated rotation and translation vector (same for all different z plane).  I am getting almost same rotation matrix, but translation matrix is different when I am taking points from different z plane

Comment: that's good. And now you have new 3D points that you want to project. They're given in which coordinate system?

Comment: same coordinate system

Comment: maybe I misunderstood... if for example the dataset with the first z-plane has point values like (x,y,0) then your second z-plane has values like (x,y,100)? In that case you should get identical r AND t on all datasets in calibration I guess. If all 3D points in all datasets share a single coordinate system you could in fact combine them to a single big dataset instead of using 4 ones.

Comment: @Micka my first dataset contains { (x1, y1, 0),  (x2, y2, 0),  (x3,y3, 0) .... }  and corresponding 2d image points,      my second dataset contains { (x1, y1, 100),  (x2, y2, 100),  (x3,y3, 100) .... } and corresponding 2d image points. my third dataset contains  { (x1, y1, 200),  (x2, y2, 200),  (x3,y3, 200) .... } and corresponding image coordinate: Now for each dataset I calculated r and t.